# How do I get thumbnails to work with the ember-carousel component?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I just installed the ember-carousel component and am using it to replace my pre-Ember js image carousel set-up that was not working well with Ember (just recently began using Ember).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-carousel

https://github.com/selvagsz/ember-carousel

So I have this code in my Handlebars templates and it works well to display all the images in a carousel:

index.hbs:

```
{{#carousel-container transition-interval=400}}
    {{#carousel-body}}
        {{#each model as |rentalUnit|}}
            {{rental-listing rental=rentalUnit}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/carousel-body}}

    {{#carousel-arrow direction="left" tagName="button"}}
        Slide Left
    {{/carousel-arrow}}
    {{#carousel-arrow direction="right" tagName="button"}}
        Slide Right
    {{/carousel-arrow}}
{{/carousel-container}}
```

rental-listing.hbs:

```
{{#carousel-item}}
  <img src={{rental.image}} alt={{rental.caption}} width="500px" />
{{/carousel-item}}
```

The carousel just has slide left/slide right buttons to browse the images. I want to also have thumbnails so you can click on a thumbnail and the carousel will display the corresponding image.

I already have the layout set up with thumbnails, I just don't know how to create this click function. Normally I would do this using jQuery and data attributes on the thumbnails to switch the currently displayed image, I'm just not sure how to create such a click function for thumbnails in this ember-carousel/handlebars template. (I'm very new to Ember/handlebars & would appreciate any help to point me in the right direction.) I'm guessing I would need to add some custom js code to carousel-container.js?: https://github.com/selvagsz/ember-carousel/tree/master/app/components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be replacing `<img src={{rental.image}} alt={{rental.caption}} width="500px" />` with a component, so you can set up the behaviour that you need. For example, if you want to do something when clicking on the image, you can use a component like this:

```
//rental-listing.hbs
{{#carousel-item}}
  {{thumbnail-image 
    image=rental.image  
    alt=rental.caption 
    thumbnailWidth="40" 
    thumbnailHeight="40" 
    imageWidth="230" 
    imageHeight="230"}}
{{/carousel-item}}

//thumbnail-image.js
  import Ember from 'ember';

  export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName:'img',
    attributeBindings:['src','alt','width','height'],
    isThumbnail:true,
    didReceiveAttrs(){
      this.set('src',this.get('image'));
      this.set('width',this.get('thumbnailWidth'));
      this.set('height',this.get('thumbnailHeight'));
    },
    click(){
      if(this.get('isThumbnail')){
        this.set('width',this.get('imageWidth'));
        this.set('height',this.get('imageHeight'));
      } else {
        this.set('width',this.get('thumbnailWidth'));
        this.set('height',this.get('thumbnailHeight'));
    }
    this.toggleProperty('isThumbnail');     
  }
});
```

You can see an example in this [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a87e835c7bb2a50ebce1?fileTreeShown=false&numColumns=2&openFiles=thumbnail-image.component.js%2Capplication.template.hbs)

Edit: I'm assuming you are using an `ember version` >= `1.13` and `Ember-cli`. If not, the code can change slightly.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it's got me in the right direction. What I need the thumbnails to do is for the thumbnail image to change ANOTHER image on the page (the full-size image that corresponds to the thumbnail). The full-size images are contained in {{carousel-body}} in my original question and the thumbnails are in a separate .hbs file, then displayed as a list in index.hbs. What I need: when the thumbnail is clicked, get the "id" attribute from the thumbnail, then find the full-size image that has that corresponding class, and set its parent div to have the class "active". Working on that.

Comment: Is the url of the full image in the `rentalUnit` model? if it is, you can pass it as a property to the `thumbnail-image` component and in the `click` event set `src` to that image.

If you want to have the thumbnail as a different `hbs`, you can create a `hbs` file for the `thumbnail-image` component and remove `tagName:'img'` so the component will wrap the `hbs` with a `div` by default.